# Exact formula or approximation for this sum (general harmonic series $H_{n,3}$)

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

I encountered the following problem in my studies. I want to calculate the requirement to the parameter $a$ for a local minimum in the function:

$F(N;a) = -a*(N-1) + \sum_i^{N-1}\sum_j^i \frac{1}{j^3} \quad N=1,2,...$

To solve this I thought the "easiest" way would be so solve the second term. But $\sum_j^i \frac{1}{j^3} = H_{i,3}$ seems to be the general harmonic series with no exact solution. Anyone has any ideas for a exact solution (for the minimum condition) or a good approximation?

Thanks

Comment: For good approximations as $i\to\infty$, use the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Examples).

Comment: What are the limits on $i$ and $j$?

Comment: ehm, the limit of i is $N-1$ and for $j$ it is $i$. $N$ should be a realistic value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simplified somewhat.

$\begin{array}\\
f(N)
&=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j^3}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=j}^{N} \frac{1}{j^3}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^3}\sum_{i=j}^{N} 1\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^3}(N-j+1)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^3}(N+1)-\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^3}j\\
&=(N+1)\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^3}-\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{j^2}\\
&\approx (N+1)\zeta(3)-\zeta(2)
\qquad\text{for large }N\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Sorry, but what is the function $\zeta(3)$ and $\zeta(2)$? EDIT: Okay nevermind, it is the Riemann Zeta function. But I am interested in the local minimum, what is already at small N, so I am not sure if this approximation is valid.

Comment: Okay with your simplification i can actually calculate the differences for $f(N+1)-f(N)$ and that helps me a lot.